# Microchip's MPLAB IDE equivalent for 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, microchip, x86-16

I always wanted to learn 8086 assembly but was (and am) a little confused on where to start. We are learning PIC16F690 at the moment in school and I'm good at it. So I guess I can give 8086 a try. I'm wondering is there an IDE for 8086 like MPLAB IDE where in it you can write code and execute instructions line by line and watch memory, registers and other stuff?

Comment: I usually simply use Notepad++ with [lzasm](http://www.phatcode.net/downloads.php?id=308) and [alink](http://alink.sourceforge.net/download.html) (+alib for Windows - it's also at ALIB site). I have a few years of experience tough :) [*Intel recommends WinASM*](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly) - don't get sidetracked by the fact that it's about x64.

Answer (score 1):

There is [WinAsm Studio](http://www.winasm.net/winasm-studio-downloads.html) which is a free IDE that works with several assemblers (TASM, FASM, MASM).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio with inline assembler using C++? or MASM?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7a1c9da0-0510-44a2-b042-7ef370530c64&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

An IDE like Delphi or VS with inline assembler is a good entry point.

The free Delphi alike Lazarus (http://lazarus.freepascal.org) is an IDE with support for 80386+ and x86_64 (x86 64-bit) colouring of assembler.